# Airflow SFTP sensor doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am building a DAG that starts with an [SFTPSensor Operator](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/sftp_sensor.html). As we can see, the SFTPSensor class takes an sftp_conn_id parameter. (Strangely, the SFTP Operator uses [an SSH connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator/index.html), which is what I would have expected from the sensor as well).

So I go to the UI to create an SFTP connection like the example sftp connection that ships with airlfow:

[image]

However this connection type does not exist among the selectable connection types. When I 'edit' the existing example, the 'type' shows up as Amazon Web Services: [image]

Do I have to create this type of connection with the CLI as [described here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#connections). So something like:

```
airflow connections -a \
--conn_id my_sftp_connection \
--conn_type sftp \
--conn_login **ux**\
--conn_port 22 \
--conn_host **host** \
--conn_extra "{"key_file": "**keypath**"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Both https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/index.html
and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/index.html use Paramiko implementation of the SSHv2 protocol.
As described here http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html paramiko sftp client uses an ssh transport to perform remote file operations.

You need to install both extra provider package's to see each connection type listed in the UI.

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-sftp[ssh]
```